# Google Maps API drawing Polygon with collection of Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a collection of Markers in an array which were pushed when user clicked on map, and need to place polygon over map using these markers. it works fine if markers are in proper order, which means when user clicked them in any particular direction.

[image: polygon when user clicked markers in correct order]

But if he user clicked on map randomly, markers would be random and the polygon looks as follows.
[image]

How can I sort these markers so that how ever the user clicked on map, I get a polygon as depicted in first image??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to find the [Convex Hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_Hull) of the points. You should find some help on [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/map-markers_ConvexHull_Polygon.asp) Google Page (You will need to view the source of the page).